# httpcontext.rewritepath -> duplicate meta tag

Tags: seo, google-search-console, url-rewriting, c#

We have a webpage that handle all car manufacturers. Page is called `vehicule.aspx`.

We have a rewrite method for SEO purpose. We gave all manufacturers a unique URL that redirects to the above page.

E.G. `www.example.com/Audi.aspx` will redirect to `www.example.com?a=Audi`

Problem is that in Google Search Console (webmaster tools) I see these 2 pages have duplicate meta tags. I use `httpcontext.rewritepath` to redirect the user. I can't find a way to set this redirect as "canonical" or something that would make this duplicate disappear from Google Search Console (webmaster tools).

There is nowhere we are referencing `?a=xyz`. It's all done internally so I don't know why Google sees this a duplicate.

Any input about this?

Comment: "redirect" / "done internally" - so is this a "redirect" or a "rewrite"? Are you sending an HTTP 3xx status code? Perhaps just a niggle, but you state "redirect to www.example.com?a=Audi", but state that the "Page is called vehicule.aspx"?

Comment: yes it's a rewrite.  It's done in c# and it's a HttpContext.rewritePath()

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.rewritepath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396